# PayPal Standard and Webform CiviCRM

Tags: webform-civicrm

visiting this page https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34814.0 Coleman said "PayPal standard feature is being added to Webform-CiviCRM right now, should be ready sometime next week." It was on November 14, 2014. Any news/update on this subject?

Comment: I'm having right now exactly the same problem and, by the way, I've found some other questions in StackExchange related to the same issue: - [Paypal Express not working with Webforms CIVICRM Intergration](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14637/paypal-express-not-working-with-webforms-civicrm-intergration) - [Webform CiviCRM Paypal Button not Working](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/webform-civicrm-paypal-button-not-working?newreg=7c48707acdda46edbc7675e4fc83d9c0) To me, it looks like an old issue that's still open. The answers to these questions suggest to upgrade the

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it should be ready for you to do some testing with. [According to this ticket it seems like Paypal Standard functionality should now be active](https://www.drupal.org/node/2286503).

*(Caveat: Webform_Civicrm is [not yet fully compatible with CiviCRM 4.7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2661232)).*

Comment: I did some testing with CiviCRM 4.7 and, previously, with CiviCRM 4.6.8 - 4.6.11, but it doesn't work. On the page [link]https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Webform+CiviCRM+Integration#WebformCiviCRMIntegration-Unsupportedpaymentprocessors it states "Currently, off-site payment processors in which a user is redirected to another site to enter their billing information — such as PayPal Website Payments Standard — are not yet supported." but it doesn't match with the November 14, 2014 claim. Unfortunately I'm not a developer so can't help on this. Hope somebody else can.