# Paypal Express not working with Webforms CIVICRM Intergration

Tags: webform-civicrm, paypal

I've upgraded Webforms to the latest version which fixed but Paypal Express CIVI payment processor is not working.

I've inputted the correct API information into the payment processor. I know its correct because we have used paypal pro successfully. The only issue with paypal pro was that when someone clicked the paypal button, it also had the same issue as paypal express. However when someone submitted the form it worked.

Paypal express doesn't work with either hitting submit or hitting paypal button.

CIVICRM 4.5.8 DRUPAL 7

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Webform CiviCRM Paypal Button not Working](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/webform-civicrm-paypal-button-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

This has been a known bug/issue in webform_civicrm ( see e.g. [Webform CiviCRM Paypal Button not Working](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/webform-civicrm-paypal-button-not-working) ) -> try upgrading to the latest webform_civicrm (dev -> clone or download master: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm.git ).

I also strongly encourage you to upgrade your CiviCRM - there have not been any security releases for 4.5.x for quite some time now.

Comment: I upgraded to 7.x-4.16, the latest version?

Comment: There was a commit on Aug. 02 that sounds promising -  Merge pull request #42 from colemanw/ipn47 - you can clone or download master: https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm.git - to test it